# Laravel cookie can increment int but not int in array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, laravel-4

I'm trying to keep a record of visits to a link in a cookie.
No, I know there are better ways of doing this, like logging to a db (which I've already implemented) but this has become a 6 hour long struggle and I'm determined to find a solution.

Firstly, incrementing a single int in a cookie works perfectly.

```
Route::get('setcookie', function () {
    $cookieName = 'd';
    ($b = Cookie::get($cookieName)) ? $b : $b = 0;
    $b = $b + 1;

    $cookie = Cookie::forever($cookieName, $b);
    $response = Response::make('Cookie test.' . $b);
    $response->withCookie($cookie);
    return $response;
});
```

The previous code increments the int without any problems.

The issue comes in when I try to increment an int ("count") within an array.
Array structure: array('count' => 0)

The following code does not increment the int.

```
Route::get('cookietest2', function () {
    $cookieName = 'c';
    ($b = Cookie::get($cookieName)) ? $b : $b = array('count' => 0);
    $b['count'] = $b['count']+1;

    print_r($b);

    $cookie = Cookie::forever($cookieName, $b);
    $response = Response::make('Cookie test.');
    $response->withCookie($cookie);
    return $response;
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[Laravel 4.2]

Thanks in advance,
Jean

Comment: is it incrementing "count" int the array?

Comment: yes so what do you want as the result ?

Comment: The result that I'm looking for is the "count" value incrementing by one each time the route is called. #1 array('count'=>0) #2 array('count'=>1) #3 array('count'=>2) and so on.. Is this the result you're getting? If so there might be an issue with my server. :/ Thanks in advance!